# How add trigger to mysql Through Schema API 

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Through Schema API (file mymodule.install in Folder sites\all\modules\mymodule).
trigger in mysql:

```
delimiter |

    CREATE TRIGGER testref AFTER INSERT ON users
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO beep  SET uid = NEW.uid;
      END;
    |

    delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific API for that.

Try http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6

Also remember that triggers are not standardised across different databases. It would be a better idea (or maybe as a fallback) to do that with hook_user().

Comment: **please explain more about relationship Between trigger in db and hook_user()**

Comment: Your trigger seems to be doing something when a new record is inserted into the {users} table. The Drupal Way (TM) of doing that is to implement hook_user(), $op = 'insert'. That will be called after a new user has been inserted into the database and then you can update your beep table

Comment: Thanks a lot.I've inserted code in line 326 of user.module. **it's work** .`db_query('INSERT INTO {beep} (uid) VALUES (%d)', $array['uid']);`

Comment: Do *not* hack core! Create a module and implement hook_user(). See http://geeksandgod.com/tutorials/computers/cms/drupal/creating-simple-drupal-module for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I've inserted code in line 326 of user.module. **it's work** .`db_query('INSERT INTO {beep} (uid) VALUES (%d)', $array['uid']);` I've a question. **Is not a problem when two records are inserted simultaneously**

Comment: ** Write module for insert a record???? ** **Whether there is a simpler solution?**

Comment: **please explain more about**

Comment: There is no simpler solution. Hacking core is *never* a solution. See http://drupal.org/node/144376. Also, you also need a module to declare that beep table and do something with it. And if you already have a module for that, you just extend it with that hook.