# how change hook_user?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

i need change hook user.I've inserted code in line 326 of user.module. it's work .`db_query('INSERT INTO {beep} (uid) VALUES (%d)', $array['uid']);`
**Do not hack core!** Please help me.

Comment: I already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301129/how-add-trigger-to-mysql-through-schema-api/5301785#5301785. Don't be that impatient ;)

Comment: no no. **The answer is not convincing**

Comment: You already hacked the core module- you need to back all of that out before any answers will help.

Comment: I do not need to convince you. This is a fact. Read the page I linked in the other comment.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom module that implements hook_user() and wrap your code in a conditional so that it fires when you want it to:

```
function my_module_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
   if( /* condition goes here */) {
      /* Do some custom processing */
      db_query('INSERT INTO {beep} (uid) VALUES (%d)', $array['uid']);
   }
}
```

Look here http://drupal.org/developing/modules for details on creating your own modules.